# ASP .NET MVC 5 Write javascript in View.cshtml file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to ASP .NET and I am struggling with javascript in MVC.
I have a IndexView.cshtml file inside View folder and would like to write a short javascript section inside to move site back to top with a button.
It works perfectly in normal html so there is that.
Normally a button shows up whenever I scroll down from top of a site and disappears when I go back up to the very top. Here it does not show up at all.
What could I do to make it work?
Thanks in advance!

So this is at the end of my body in IndexView.cshtml right before `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });

        });
    </script>
    <a href="#" id="toTop"><span id="toTopHover"> </span></a>
```

And this it the part of move-top.js inside Scripts folder /Scripts/move-top.js

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.UItoTop = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            text: 'To Top', min: 200, inDelay: 600, outDelay: 400, containerID: 'toTop', containerHoverID: 'toTopHover',
            scrollSpeed: 1200, easingType: 'linear'
        }, settings = $.extend(defaults, options), containerIDhash = '#' + settings.containerID, containerHoverIDHash = '#' + settings.containerHoverID;
        $('body').append('<a href="#" id="' + settings.containerID + '">' + settings.text + '</a>');
        $(containerIDhash).hide().on('click.UItoTop', function ()
        {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, settings.scrollSpeed, settings.easingType);
            $('#' + settings.containerHoverID, this).stop().animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, settings.inDelay, settings.easingType); return false;
        }).prepend('<span id="' + settings.containerHoverID + '"></span>').hover(function ()
        { $(containerHoverIDHash, this).stop().animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 600, 'linear'); }, function ()
        { $(containerHoverIDHash, this).stop().animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 700, 'linear'); });
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var sd = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (typeof document.body.style.maxHeight === "undefined")
            {
                $(containerIDhash).css({
                    'position': 'absolute', 'top': sd + $(window).height() - 50
                });
            }
if(sd>settings.min)
$(containerIDhash).fadeIn(settings.inDelay);else
$(containerIDhash).fadeOut(settings.Outdelay);});};})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I don't see a question here. Just a goal and some code. What's your problem?

Comment: What isn't working?  ASP.NET MVC views are based on HTML like any other website.  What's preventing you from putting JavaScript in them just as you would in your HTML file?

Comment: OH sorry, It just isn't working ;). Normally on my page button shows up whenever I scroll down from top but here it does not. Looks like it's not even recognizing my code.

Comment: You should try doing the basics, and describe what you've checked in your posts. For example, making sure scripts loaded correctly, checking for JavaScript errors in the developer console, stepping through the code, etc.

Comment: @mason For now I've included my other scripts which run entirely outside of my cshtml file as such for example and they all work just fine:
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")"></script>

Comment: @TheGalax Please edit your question to state what you've tried, we don't need to see it in a comment. At a *minimum*, try what I listed in my last comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like your js code is dependent on the jQuery library. That means you need to load jQuery code before execcuting this code.

In the Layout file,  `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` is called at the very bottom after loading jQuery library.

```
<div id="pageContent">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

And in your view, you should be including any script which is dependent of jQuery inside the `Scripts` section so that when the page is fully rendered, it will be added to the bottom ( After other libraries like jQuery is loaded);

```
<h2>This is my View</h2>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
      $(function(){
         alert("All good");
      });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added @section Scripts{} to my script and it looks like it works now :) only thing that is missing now is that the button is transparent, looks like the .img didn't load properly.

Answer (score 1):

@TheGalax did you remember to reference your javascript file?

-- Added jQuery --

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/move-top.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I've made it that way:
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/move-top.js")"></script>

Comment: It's always a good idea to post your full cshtml, to give better context to your question.  @Shyju has the next best guess :)  see edit above