# How to call the controller from the radio button click?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, radiobuttonlist

How to call the controller from the radio button click ?

```
    <div id="radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Isactive" name="Isactive" value="1" />Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="Isactive" name="Isactive" value="0" />No</label>
</div>

 public ActionResult Index(CityList Obj,string Isactive)
     {
      return view();


     }
```

Comment: like a form submit or ajax call ?

Comment: @ Shyju form submit.

Comment: your action method expects a CityList object. Does your form have the input elements to bind to that ?\

Comment: @ Shyju . it also expects a string "Isactive" . How can get the value of the radio button in  controller?.

Comment: What checkbox ? your question has radio buttons!

Comment: @ Shyju. sir It was a typing mistake. I mean radio button. I am new to this MVC architecture ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to programatically submit a form. You should not have duplicate Id values for elements. Id's should be unique in a document.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    <!-- Your other form elements-->
    <div id="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="Isactive" value="Yes" />Yes
        <input type="radio" name="Isactive" value="No" />No
    </div>
}
```

Now you can listen to the change event on the radio button and use jQuery `closest` method to get the form and call the `submit` method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input[name='Isactive']").change(function () {
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });

});
```

Now when user make a selection on the radio button, the form will be submitted and the selected radio button's value attribute value will be available in your `Isactive` parameter of your HttpPost index action method.

If you want to pass `1` and `0`, use a numeric type as the method parameter type instead of `string`.

Comment: What specifically does not work ? It is not making the form submit  ? Is your radio button inside a form ? Do you have any script errors preventing the js code to be executed ? check your browser console.

Comment: @ Shyju 3 . yes. there is a script error when I check the browser console 
 "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: That means, you are using the jQuery code before the jQuery library is included. Check the view source of the page and see whether you have any code which is using jquery before the line which includes the library. You can use Sections to include your page level script load after you load jQuery. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519342/asp-net-mvc-5-write-javascript-in-view-cshtml-file/34519508#34519508