# Visual Studio interprets JavaScript as C# which causes errors

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

Here in my code in my ASP.NET Core project I have that's causing the issue:[image: Code in question]

As Text:

```
<script>
/**
     * Get a setting value.
     * @param {string} name
     * @param defaultValue
     * @returns {*}
     */
    getSetting(name, defaultValue) {
        return name in this.settings ? this.settings[name] : defaultValue;
    }
</script>
```

The error that I'm getting for every documentation code, which is red lined is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103
which gets clearly identified as C# code, even though I'm writing this code in a .cshtml file `<script>` tag...

How do I fix this? It prevents me from compiling and executing...

I am using Visual Studio 2022 Preview 4.1 if that matters

Comment: Please provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably in a code snippet. Do not post pictures of your code as we like to copy and paste the code rather than rewrite it.

Comment: You should provide more of the .cshtml file that these lines are part of

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP .NET MVC 5 Write javascript in View.cshtml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519342/asp-net-mvc-5-write-javascript-in-view-cshtml-file)

Comment: @Rojo no, that's a completely different problem

Comment: @KarloX please check the question. Thanks for not giving downvotes/close votes instantly and mercilessly

Comment: .cshtml files are interpreted as Razor templates where `@` is used to mark C# code in the template. Either escape with a second @ i.e. `@@param` etc or move the JS to a separate file

Comment: @phuzi that explains it. How do I solve this? Is there a manual override or something like that?

Comment: Just updated my comment ^^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.cshtml files are interpreted as Razor templates where `@` is used to mark C# code in the template.

You can either escape with a second @ i.e. `@@param` etc or move the JS to a separate file.